# Is possible to use GetX and Provider in one project?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-getx, state-management

I want create a project with two State Management Getx and Provider, my reason is, as a beginner I easy to use Provider to manage my fetch data and show it, while I use GetX to remove a lot of boiler-plate(ex. navigate, size of widget etc), so while I use both, is a bad step for me or what ?, your guys opinion is good for my reference, thank you.

Comment: use whatever you like, one that you can work on, understand and that can fullfil your need !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can easily use Getx and provider in one project.
1: You can use Getx for Routing and size etc,
2: provider for statemanagement.